# Open codeigniter projects with TextWrangler

Tags: codeigniter, editor, textwrangler

I have seen some people opening codeigniter as project while I am still opening separate files
which is really slow...does anybody know how can I do that with TextWrangler?

Answer (score 0):

from terminal you can use it similar to textmate. navigate to the folder you want to open in terminal and execute:

textmate:

```
mate .
```

textwrangler:

```
open -a /applications/textwrangler.app .
```

hope this helps